# I'm newbie and Need help, with php array call. I do use var_dump and show this

Tags: php, arrays

first I'm looking help from any expert here for PHP array calling. I try using `var_dump` but still I can't call my data. I'm really a beginner and need a lot of help. Thanks before for read my question below...

```
<?php var_dump($this->product->customfieldsSorted); ?>
```

I use that and get this array list...

```
array(1) {
["normal"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#222 (36) {
    ["virtuemart_custom_id"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["custom_parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["virtuemart_vendor_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["custom_jplugin_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["custom_element"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["admin_only"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["custom_title"]=>
    string(5) "Slide"
    ["show_title"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["custom_tip"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["custom_value"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["custom_desc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["field_type"]=>
    string(1) "M"
    ["is_list"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["is_hidden"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_cart_attribute"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["is_input"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["layout_pos"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["custom_params"]=>
    string(26) "width="1024"|height="400"|"
    ["shared"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["published"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ordering"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["virtuemart_customfield_id"]=>
    string(3) "110"
    ["virtuemart_product_id"]=>
    string(2) "95"
    ["customfield_value"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["customfield_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["customfield_params"]=>
    string(25) "width="200"|height="200"|"
    ["fpublished"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["override"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["disabler"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["_varsToPushParamCustom"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["width"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "200"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "string"
      }
      ["height"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "200"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "string"
      }
    }
    ["_varsToPushParamCustomField"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["width"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "200"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "string"
      }
      ["height"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "200"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "string"
      }
    }
    ["_varsToPushParam"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["width"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "200"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "string"
      }
      ["height"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "200"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "string"
      }
    }
    ["width"]=>
    string(3) "200"
    ["height"]=>
    string(3) "200"
    ["_xParams"]=>
    string(18) "customfield_params"
    ["display"]=>
    string(101) "<img src="/angga/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/marinecap_200x200.jpg" alt="marinecap"  />"
  }
}
```

Nah I want to get the:

```
["display"]=>
string(101) "<img src="/angga/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/marinecap_200x200.jpg" alt="marinecap"  />"
```

using this:

```
<?php echo $this->product->customfieldsSorted->display;?>
```

and got nothing. Can anyone help? I have no clue. None at all. Thanks before :)

Comment: $this->product->customfieldsSorted[0]->display

Comment: Nope @splash58 it should be `$this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'][0]->display`

Comment: @Uchiha Yes, you are right

Comment: @splash58 Thanks allot! Oh that's the point why array data always need the right pointer :S

Comment: @Uchiha Do you know that your alias sounds in Russian about as "school-teach" feminine ? :)

Comment: For array indexes you use `[ ]`. For object properties you use `->`. In this case `customfieldsSorted` is an array with one item with a named index `'normal'`, which contains one item with a numeric index `0`, which contains an *object* with (amongst others) the property `display`.

Comment: @splash58 Nope I don't think so :P

Comment: @Uchiha i'm sure :) It may be more dismissive between children together.

Comment: @Uchiha Thanks for improve the answer!

Comment: You're welcome/ Glad it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->product->customfieldsSorted` is an array with the key `"normal"`, you can get corresponding value: `$this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal']`.

`$this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal']` is an array with the key `0`, get its value: `$this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'][0]`.

`$this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'][0]` is an object of `stdClass`, you can get value of the property `display` using `$this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'][0]->display`.